# TypeError: shows.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
// import { navigate } from '@reach/router'
import axios from 'axios';

function SearchBar() {
const [shows, setShows] = useState({});

function getShows() {
    axios.get('http://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=office')
        .then(response => {
            setShows({ data: response.data })
        })
        .catch(console.log)
};


return (
    <div>
        <button onClick={getShows}>Get Show</button>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {shows.map(show => (
                    <tr key={show.id}>
                        <td>{show.name}</td>
                        <td>{show.summary}</td>
                    </tr>
                ))}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
  )
 }

 export default SearchBar;
```

``

i'm losing it and i cant figure out why i'm getting the error "TypeError: shows.map is not a function"

Comment: map() is an Array method. You can't use them for object type. shows state is an object. Here's a reference to learn more https://dev.to/davisbwake/javascript-high-order-array-methods-1og0

Answer (score 1):

You store the data in an object instead of an aray.

change

```
const [shows, setShows] = useState({}) 
setShows({ data: response.data })
```

to

```
const [shows, setShows] = useState([])
setShows(response.data)
```

Answer (score 0):

`useState` takes an argument which it uses as the inital value for the state variable, in your case, `shows`. You pass it `{}`, which is an [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) and doesn't have a `map` function. Instead you want to pass it `[]` to initialize it to an [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) which *does* have a `map` function.

When this is all put together, you end up with `const [shows, setShows] = useState([]);`